# Lighttable truncating data display

Tags: clojure, lighttable

I'm new to both Clojure and Lighttable. I'm following along with the [Casting SPELs in Clojure](http://www.lisperati.com/clojure-spels/casting.html) tutorial. Although Lighttable is doing a great job of displaying all this dynamic data for me (most let me hover to view full text), it truncates the descriptions of rooms/items.

[Here's a snip](http://imgur.com/uoggxre) of what I'm looking at. The descriptions appear in the green text. The first one, describing the living-room, displays completely. But later on, the tutorial introduces functions and macros for printing more complicated descriptions, and they truncate as seen here when describing paths. Hovering doesn't display full text.

I haven't found a lot of documentation for Lighttable, so I'm not sure specifically why it's doing this or how to change it. It might be something Clojure-specific that I don't understand, but the tutorial uses a regular REPL and displays everything just fine.

Comment: You probably want to ask this here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/light-table-discussion

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of light table (0.4), you can see untruncated values by printing to the console (choose `Console: Toggle bottom console` or `Console: Open the console in a tab` from the command bar).

Print to the console using `(println "a string")` or Clojure's pretty print function for maps and other data structures:

```
 (use 'clojure.pprint)
 (pprint {:description "pretend this is a complex map that would normally be truncated"})
```